# Install LiveCD Partition

Tags: live-environment

Ubuntu has a LiveCD version that is able to boot alongside the regular installation and is useful for tasks like repartitioning the system drive.

I am able to put the LiveCD onto a CD/DVD or USB media.

How can I put the LiveCD onto an internal hard drive such that it is installed alongside the main installation?  I would imagine that it would be useful for performing such maintenance tasks as well as if I want to test software without persisting changes.

Note that from the installed LiveCD partition, I'd expect that it runs just as if I had booted it off a CD/DVD/USB in that it loads up a live environment and stores changes in memory without touching disks until I manually mount them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Grub-n-ISO

You can boot from an iso file via grub in your installed system. It is possible to configure it in the file `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` and make it active by running

```
sudo update-grub
```

which copies its menuentry to `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

This is described in detail via the following links and links from them,

- [help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot)
- [help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples) with content to add to the file `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`

  Modified example (updated to Xenial alias 16.04.1 LTS). Use the actual path and name to the iso file and the actual partition in the loopback command.

  ```
  menuentry 'Ubuntu Xenial alias 16.04.1 LTS' {
   set isofile="/iso/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso"
   loopback loop (hd0,5)$isofile
   linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject
   initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
  }
  ```
- [www.howtogeek.com/196933/how-to-boot-linux-iso-images-directly-from-your-hard-drive](https://www.howtogeek.com/196933/how-to-boot-linux-iso-images-directly-from-your-hard-drive/) with detailed tips
- [wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multiboot_USB_drive](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multiboot_USB_drive) with more examples and links
- [help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Chainloading](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Chainloading) how to use the file `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`

Answer (score 1):

you can do exactly this, ubuntu has a step by step guide for doing it from linux, it involves making a new partition and setting up grub to read it as an operating system - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromLinux

Answer (score 0):

All maintenance software in the Live CD can be installed into your existing Ubuntu installation too. Take GParted partition manager for example, you can install it by executing this in terminal: `sudo apt-get install gparted`. You can perform operation such as resizing or deleting partitions from Ubuntu itself using GParted: right click on target partition (except the current Ubuntu partition itself) and unmount it, then you can modify the partition. Do be careful when working with partitions.

If it is the Ubuntu partition itself you want to modify, then you will either have to use a Live CD or Live USB. Or being fancy, you can have multiple Ubuntu installation in the same hard disk on a different partition from the first Ubuntu installation. By default Ubuntu doesn't mount any partition automatically anyway.

Even more fancy (and safer), would be to boot the Live CD disc image from [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), then do an install for messing around with all Linux goodness safely. Have fun!

Comment: "multiple Ubuntu installation in the same hard disk on a different partition from the first Ubuntu installation" is exactly what I am looking for. Although I want it to be minimal and volitile just the same as the LiveCD such that no changes are persisted. That partition shouldn't need to be much bigger than the LiveCD itself.  I don't want a full normal install in the second partition.

Comment: I see. That's easily done. Do a full Ubuntu install on another partition (sized bigger than Live CD to accommodate the temporary changes, e.g. add 1GB if u intend to test software that consume that much for install and other additional files). Then enable Guest session and login using the Guest account whenever you want things to be reset after logging out. More details here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession